# nginx - Setup HTTPS Rest API on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, https

On an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18, I am running an express server that serves a REST API. I am trying to secure the server with HTTPS because the website that utilizes the API has a `.app` domain, so any content the website accesses must also use HTTPS. Otherwise, I get a "Mixed Content" error.

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/serving-a-website-on-a-registered-domain-with-https-using-nginx-and-lets-encrypt-8d482e01a682) guide for serving a website on a registered domain with HTTPS using Nginx and Let's Encrypt. At one point, the guide says to add the following to my nginx configuration file, where "example.com" and "www.example.com", should be replaced with my actual domain name.

```
server {
   listen       80 default_server;
   listen       [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name  example.com www.example.com;
   root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

However, I am not serving a website from my server (the actual website is being hosted on Github Pages)--rather I am just serving an API, like this: http://ec2-my-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api_endpoint

Do I still replace "example.com" with my website's domain name, or do I replace it with ec2-my-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api_endpoint

Furthermore, can I remove the `root` setting because I am not serving any HTML pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is impossible to get a Let's Encrypt certificate for an AWS domain name because they explictly blacklist AWS: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/policy-forbids-issuing-for-name-on-amazon-ec2-domain/12692/4

> We specifically list the amazonaws domans because we know they are ephemeral. We might certify one as belonging to you today, and then it could belong to someone else tomorrow.